# Ways to Fade JLabels?

Tags: java, swing, transparency, jlabel

I am having trouble with a game I am making. I am attempting to fade a JLabel, using a Timer. So far, I have been able to set a JLabel as transparent, and I have been able to make a working Timer. But somehow, I am not able to combine them together. I can set a JLabel's background to

```
l.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 200));
```

(l being desired JLabel to change the color of, of course)
and it works. The JLabel is transparent. 
But I have not been able to put it into a timer so that the color fades:

```
public static void fadeLabel(JLabel lab, int steps, int target) {
    class fade extends Thread {
        public void run() {
            Timer t = new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println(lab.getBackground().getAlpha());
                    lab.setBackground(new 
                    Color(lab.getBackground().getRed(), 
                    lab.getBackground().getGreen(), 
                    lab.getBackground().getBlue(), 
                    lab.getBackground().getAlpha() + steps));
                    if (lab.getBackground().getAlpha() == target) {
                        ((Timer) e.getSource()).stop();
                    }
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }
    }
    new Thread(new fade()).start();
}
```

instead, it just goes from black to transparent. Nothing in-between. It also throws the error `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Color parameter outside of expected range: Alpha`. However, I have set the step to -5 (the rate at which it fades, in this case, fades out, as it is negative) and if you remember, I set the alpha to something that is divisible by five, and I also have a checker for when it gets to the target, so that it stops the Timer when it reaches that target. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Is the JLabel's background updating too fast for it to show? Any help would be great.

Edit:
I have fixed the `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Color parameter outside of expected range: Alpha`. But the other one about the JLabel not fading is still there, and I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: You need to provide code that I can download and run.

Comment: @Abra I will provide as much or as little code as you like. May I ask what all you need?

Comment: A small, complete program that uses the code you already posted. A java class with a `main` method that builds your _Swing_ GUI and launches your label fading code.

Comment: Are you expecting the timer to trigger the callback 10 times?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not directly answering your question. A wrote some code, take a look :D

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class MyWindow extends JFrame {

    public MyWindow() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        setTitle( "Fading labels :)" );
        setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        setSize( 400, 400 );
        setLocationRelativeTo( null );
        setLayout( new FlowLayout() );

        for ( int i = 0; i < 550; i++ ) {
            JLabel lab = new JLabel( "x" );
            add( lab );
            fadeLabel( lab, 10, i / 10, 0 );
        }

    }

    private void fadeLabel( JLabel label, int steps, int skipSteps, int targetAlpha ) {
        new LabelFader( label, steps, skipSteps, targetAlpha ).start();
    }

    private class LabelFader {

        JLabel label;
        int steps;
        int skipSteps;
        int targetAlpha;

        LabelFader( JLabel label, int steps, int skipSteps, int targetAlpha ) {
            this.label = label;
            this.steps = steps;
            this.skipSteps = skipSteps;
            this.targetAlpha = targetAlpha;
        }

        void start() {

            Color startColor = label.getForeground();
            int startAlpha = startColor.getAlpha();
            int deltaAlpha = startAlpha - targetAlpha;

            if ( deltaAlpha > 0 ) {

                int alphaStep = deltaAlpha / steps;

                new Thread( new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {

                        int totalIterations = steps + skipSteps;
                        int currIteration = 1;

                        for ( int i = 0; i < totalIterations; i++ ) {

                            if ( skipSteps == 0 ) {

                                int newAlpha = startAlpha - alphaStep * currIteration++;
                                newAlpha = newAlpha < 0 ? 0 : newAlpha;

                                Color newColor = new Color( 
                                        startColor.getRed(), 
                                        startColor.getGreen(), 
                                        startColor.getGreen(),
                                        newAlpha );

                                label.setForeground( newColor );

                            } else {
                                skipSteps--;
                            }

                            try {
                                Thread.sleep( 100 );
                            } catch ( InterruptedException exc ) {
                                exc.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        Color newColor = new Color( 
                                startColor.getRed(), 
                                startColor.getGreen(), 
                                startColor.getGreen(),
                                targetAlpha );

                        label.setForeground( newColor );

                    }
                }).start();

            }

        }

    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MyWindow().setVisible( true );
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks man, I’ll try it. Not sure if using Thread.sleep(); is the best way, but I will attempt it.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to condense this down into a single method that you can just put in a JLabel and required parameters, and it fades it? I'm not the best with classes and their methods, so in trying to turn it into just a method it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: can you make the method accessible from other classes as well? @davidbuzzato

Answer (score 0):

## SECOND EDIT:

Here's some sample code that works. It'll throw the `Exception` you've already fixed but this is just for demonstration purposes only :).

Play with the `label.setOpaque` and its background and tell what happens with yourself. If you need to draw the label background set that flag to true.

If you do not need to draw its background do not modify label's background and do not set it to be opaque and modifying the foreground color should be more than enough! :)

```
package main;


import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    JLabel label;
    JButton btn;

    public Main() {
        setSize(500,500);
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        label = new JLabel("My super awesome label");
        //label.setOpaque(true); //Play with these lines and see what happens
        //label.setBackground(Color.BLUE); //Play with these lines and see what happens

        btn = new JButton("Click me");
        btn.setSize(200,200);
        btn.addActionListener(
                (ActionEvent evt) -> {
                    Timer t = new Timer(100,
                            (ActionEvent event) -> {
                                Color foreground = label.getForeground();
                                Color background = label.getBackground();

                                foreground = decreaseAlpha(foreground);
                                background = decreaseAlpha(background);

                                label.setForeground(foreground);
                                label.setBackground(background);
                            }
                        );

                    t.start();
                }
        );

        this.add(label);
        this.add(btn);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        (new Main()).setVisible(true);
    }

    public Color decreaseAlpha(Color original) {
        return new Color(original.getRed(), original.getGreen(), original.getBlue(), original.getAlpha() - 10);
    }
}
```

## EDIT:

You might be changing your background of your label instead of its foreground...

```
Timer t = new Timer(10, (ActionEvent evt)-> {
    l.setForeground(new 
        Color(l.getForeground().getRed(), 
        l.getForeground().getGreen(), 
        l.getForeground().getBlue(), 
        l.getForeground().getAlpha() - 1)
    );
    l.invalidate();
});
t.start();
```

Being `l` your label

Also, don't do this:

`new Thread(new fade()).start();`

Your `fade` class is already a `Thread` because it's extending it. Use `(new fade()).start();` instead

Comment: I am not expecting to call it 10 times. I understand that there is a 10 millisecond delay between each firing, which is why I added the if then statement to stop it. What I’m having trouble with is why the jLabel is not fading. Could it be that 10ms is too fast for the task?

Comment: nope, I know for sure that I am only setting the background of the JLabel.

Comment: Yes and that is why is not working. you should set the JLabel's Foreground instead.

Comment: thanks, I will try it. But I thought foreground was text?

Comment: yeah it’s just text. I tried it, the JLabel was only white and didn’t fade at all.

Comment: The components are drawn with two layers: Background and foreground. JLabels are not opaque by default which means the background changes won't be visually appreciable. If you set the label to be opaque, then the background of your label will be "drawn".

So in order to fully fade out your label you should apply the color transformations to both background and foreground components of your JLabel while having set the JLabel to be opaque when you instantiated it.

Comment: I will try that. To sum it up and make sure I am understanding, you’re saying set both foreground and background to the new color and setting it opaque to false before and then to opaque to true after?

Comment: First part: yes, the second no. You should `label.setOpaque(true)` as soon as you add it to your JFrame

Comment: And in your timer function make the color transforms to background and foreground

Comment: Tomorrow I can share a short snippet of what I mean since I've already shut down my machine

Comment: yeah I tried both, neither have worked.  And my JLabel is set to Opaque.

Comment: anything else you can suggest for me?

Comment: There's a new small snippet that demonstrates how that works. If you use the same code and still doesn't quite work for you then I'd suggest you to check in other places of your code what you're doing with that label.

Also share more code of yours so we can get a better understanding of what's going on and it's easier to help you out!

Comment: I would also like to add that if you're looking into game development, unless it is a very basic game, don't use Swing as your graphical library...

Comment: what library would you recommend

Comment: Since you're familiar with Swing I'd recommend you to try JavaFX which is basically its sucessor. Also there are a ton of other languages and game engines that are better suited for game development like Unity, Unreal Engine and others.

Also give a try to Unity and C# since C# from my perspective is like Java but x10 times better since it's easier to write and has more features. But that's just an opinion.

Comment: it seems that `decreaseAlpha();` does not exist as a method in Java. EDIT: sorry didn't see you just declared a new Method

Comment: seems your code doesn't work. can you condense it into a static Method I can call instead of an entire demo?

Answer (score 0):

A `JLabel` is not opaque by default, so its background is not painted. Therefore changing its background color will have no effect - unless you explicitly made your `JLabel` opaque by calling the relevant method, as in

```
lab.setOpaque(true)
```

Forgive me but I couldn't find that in the code you posted.

Also, code that affects the GUI needs to be performed on the *Event Dispatch Thread* (EDT). Your code that changes the `JLabel` background color is being run in a separate thread. The result of running that code is therefore unpredictable. The `javax.swing.Timer` class does not need to be run in a separate thread. Simply create a `Timer` object and then call its `start` method. So just take your code that creates the `Timer` out of the `Thread` and put it in with the rest of your GUI code.

If you would like a small, demo program showing how to fade the text of a `JLabel`, let me know.

EDIT: Here is the demo that fades the `JLabel` text. A `JFrame` containing a `JLabel` and a `JButton`. Click the `JButton` and the `JLabel` text fades until it disappears.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

/**
 * Tests <i>Swing</i> {@link javax.swing.Timer timer}.
 */
public class LabelDim {
    private int alpha;
    private JButton button;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel label;
    private Timer timer;

    public LabelDim() {
        timer = new Timer(200, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (alpha > 0) {
                    alpha -= 15;
                    label.setForeground(new Color(0, 0, 0, alpha));
                }
                else {
                    timer.stop();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void showGui() {
        frame = new JFrame("Dim");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        label = new JLabel("I am a fading label.", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        alpha = label.getForeground().getAlpha();
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(24.0f));
        label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 20, 10, 20));
        frame.add(label, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        button = new JButton("Start");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                timer.start();
            }
        });
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(button);
        frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LabelDim instance = new LabelDim();
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> instance.showGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: A demo program would be lovely. And I already set the opaqueness of the JLabel to true, sorry for leaving that out.